# Detect if SQL Connection is using Alias (Configuration Manager)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-connection

I have a entry in SQL Server Configuration Manager>SQL Native client Configuration > Aliases

```
Alias Name : CRM_APP
Port : 5051
Protocol: TCP/IP
Server: 10.10.10.10\MYSERVER
```

I am connecting to SQL using

```
Servername : CRM_APP
```

How can we detect if a SQL connection is using Alias (basically i want to know the actual IP address of the Server that the client is using) to connect to the Server using SQL or C#?

*Clearer explanation of requirement copied from comments:*

> Basically I want to restrict Winforms Application Login only to LAN.
>   If a user tries to connect to a server over internet, it should not be
>   allowed. BUT we dont want to do it using Firewall policies or SQL
>   Logon Triggers. We have handled the connections if it is using hosts
>   file. Now we need to take care of Aliases

Comment: Where do you want to perform this detection? From the client or from the server?

Comment: I want to detect it on client for login event. Also it would be Ok if it is detected on Server, i can read back the data to client using SQL query if needed.

Comment: In addition to @Damien, when do you want to know this and from what code? If just from the client, after connecting and using a `DbConnection`, you can just access the latter's [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.datasource.aspx) property to get the server address.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Datasource property returns back CRM_APP. But the output i am expecting is the Server mentioned in Alias i.e. 10.10.10.10\MYSERVER mentioned in this example.

Comment: That's tricky; I'm not sure the .NET level will know about that (it happens a bit further down); I assume `@@servername` is also not usable?

Comment: @MarcGravell, Yes @@ServerName is not usable. It will be fine if we are able to detect it at .NET or SQL level. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SERVERPROPERTY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx):

- `SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')`: Both the Windows server and instance information associated with a specified instance of SQL Server.
- `SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')`: Windows computer name on which the server instance is running. For a clustered instance, an instance of SQL Server running on a virtual server on Microsoft Cluster Service, it returns the name of the virtual server.
- `SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS')`: NetBIOS name of the local computer on which the instance of SQL Server is currently running. For a clustered instance of SQL Server on a failover cluster, this value changes as the instance of SQL Server fails over to other nodes in the failover cluster. On a stand-alone instance of SQL Server, this value remains constant and returns the same value as the MachineName property.

### Update

BTW if you want your application to connect exclusively to a well known server, leverage SSL/TLS:

- Specify [`Encrypt=True`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.encrypt.aspx) in the connection string used by application. This will trigger SSL/TLS required on the connection.
- Specify FQDN for the server, see [Encrypting Connections to SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), specifically the `SQL Server Native Client Certificate Requirements` section.
- Install a certificate on the server for SQL use, see `Configuring SSL For SQL Server` in the same link above.
- add the server's certificate to the trusted certificates on the client

This way you are adding a significant barrier to any attempt to 'hijack' the application connection.

Comment: Hello @Remus, I want to detect the Server Value entered in the SQL Native Client Alias. So Basically in above example, the output i want is 10.10.10.10\MYSERVER or 10.10.10.10 i.e. the actual public IP of the SQL server to which client is connecting using Alias.

Comment: A client does not connect to an IP. Connects to a server. There are connection protocols that do not involve any IP (shared memory). Besides alias there are many more forms of indirection (eg. hosts file) so in the end the only thing that matter is the actual server you're connected to.

Comment: Basically I want to restrict Winforms Application Login only to LAN. If a user tries to connect to a server over internet,  it should not be allowed. BUT we dont want to do it using Firewall policies or SQL Logon Triggers. We have handled the connections if it is using hosts file. Now we need to take care of Aliases

Comment: You're doing an incorrect hack at the wrong layer that will not work. The tool **is** Firewall policies, combined with IPSec if needed.

Comment: Well I know and was trying to find if any alternative is available, Network team wanted this to be implemented at the Application Layer. Thank you.

Comment: Fitting a square plug in a round hole... What if I run netcat locally and forward the port out of LAN? What if I run netcat in the LAN and connect to it and forward the port outside? Application Layer is helpless.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've exactly understood your requirement, but might one possibility (assuming you're using SQL 2005 or later) be to query the `sys.dm_exec_connections` management view from the client? The query would be something like:

```
SELECT  session_id, local_net_address, client_net_address 
FROM    sys.dm_exec_connections 
WHERE   session_id = @@SPID
```

Access to `sys.dm_exec_connections` requires the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission, so you might need to wrap the query in a stored procedure, view or function to avoid granting your application login this permission.

Comment: When i run above query from client, it gives me local IP of the server. What i want is the IP used by the Client (connecting over internet) to Connect to the SQL Server.

Comment: @Thakur - that isn't clear from your question - the alias has nothing directly to do with the Client machine's IP. See my edit - I've added `client_net_address` to the resultset, which should give you what you want.

Comment: Sorry if that was not clear. Please check edit "(basically i want to know the actual IP address of the Server that the client is using". I want the IP address of the server that client is using to connect.